# Find the sum of the series $\sum^{\infty}_{n=2}\ln(1- \frac{1}{n^2})$

Tags: calculus

I got $0$ which is the wrong answer. I got $0$ because $1/n^2$ just goes to $0$ so you're left with $\ln(1)$ which is $0$.

Comment: But it is a sum.  The first term is $\ln \frac 34 \approx -0.287$ and all the other terms are negative as well, so it is definitely less than$ -0.287$.  Certainly the terms converge to $0$.

Comment: Two hints:  $1-\frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{n^2 - 1}{n^2}$  and  $\ln(\frac{a}{b}) = \ln(a) - \ln(b)$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** The sum of logarithms is the logarithm of the product, which will ultimately telescope. The final answer is $-\ln2$.